# Create a AngularJS Filter str.slice(0,10)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have this string and I want to create a filter to cut the last 10 chars

thanks

```
var date ="2014-04-15T07:00:00.000Z";

date = str.slice(0,10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var date ="2014-04-15T07:00:00.000Z";
date = date.substring(0, date.length - 10);
```

removes the last 10 characters of variable `date` and returns `"2014-04-15T07:"`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/eebyG/1/).

Comment: i have a json array {date:"2014-04-15T07:00:00.000Z",date:"2014-04-15T07:00:00.000Z",date:"2014-04-15T07:00:00.000Z"}

the filter is for print {{date|slice(10)} or something like that.
but i'm beginner in angular.

Comment: note. i know how to do a angular app, but i never worked with filters